# Receiving jpeg photos from Arduino on PC in binary format

Tags: binary, arduino, jpeg, sd-card, binaryfiles

To begin with, I need to extract jpeg format photos from an SD card to my computer using an Arduino + SD shield. So, I made a sketch that opens a test photo(formula.jpg) and prints the binary code to serial console. To have the binary code in a file I use another program written in Processing that reads the serial console and writes the output in a .txt file.(formula.txt).

My aim is to write the .txt file with the binary code of the .jpg and then rename it to .jpg so if code is okay I'll have my photo. Although, I receive a file that is in size 790kB when the original is 490kB. I've opened the original photo in .txt and I see that the code is almost similar with the one I receive from arduino but for some symbols I get the "replacement symbol"(black rhombus with a question mark) or something else or maybe another symbol is added...

Like this:

```
Original: Ψΰ JFIF  H H  Ϋ C 
Received: �Ψ�ΰ JFIF  H H  �Ϋ C 

Original: Y_¤PΡ€Q,
Received: Y_¤PΡ�€Q,
```

Because I'am totally new to this and I know you can't mess with binary I need some help with the code and some guidance here to achieve this eventually.

Here is the code that prints the binary of .jpg to serial console.

```cpp
#include <SdFat.h>

SdFat sd;
SdFile myFile;
const int chipSelect = 10;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);

if (!sd.begin(chipSelect, SPI_FULL_SPEED)) sd.initErrorHalt();

if (!myFile.open("formula.jpg", O_READ)) {
sd.errorHalt("opening file for read failed");
}
Serial.println("formula.jpg:");

int data;
while ((data = myFile.read()) >= 0) Serial.write(data);

myFile.close();
}

void loop() {}    
// nothing happens after setup
```

and here's the Processing code that writes the .txt file

```cpp
// ReceiveBinaryData
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort; // Create object from Serial class
PrintWriter output;

short portIndex = 0;
char HEADER = ':';

void setup()
{
// Open whatever serial port is connected to Arduino.
String portName = Serial.list()[portIndex];
println(Serial.list());
println(" Connecting to -> " + Serial.list()[portIndex]);
myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 115200);

output = createWriter("formula.txt");
}

void draw()
{ 
if( myPort.read() == HEADER) // after header is the jpg binary
{
  byte[] inBuffer = new byte[7];
  while (myPort.available() > 0) {
  inBuffer = myPort.readBytes();
  if (inBuffer != null) {
   String value = new String(inBuffer);
   output.print(value);
   print(value);
}}}}
```

I would be very pleased if I could find a way to achieve this because I'm not doing it just for experimenting. I need to extract some photos from a damaged SD card that I can read it only from Arduino SPI mode when it appears dead on camera and computer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using OutputStream instead of PrintWriter and modifying the Processing code solved the problem for me :D

```js
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;
OutputStream output;

 void setup() {

  size(320, 240);
  myPort = new Serial( this, Serial.list()[0], 115200);
  myPort.clear();

  output = createOutput("test.jpg");
}

void draw() {

  try { 
    while ( myPort.available () > 0 ) {
      output.write(myPort.read());
    }
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}


void keyPressed() {

  try { 
    output.flush();  // Writes the remaining data to the file
    output.close();  // Finishes the file
  } 

  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```